# Getting all weapons for 100% completion

Tags: far-cry-4

In the menu's **progress** section says I need to get **64 weapons** in order to achieve 100% completion, but I have no idea where to get all of them. 
The shop only sells half of them and online guides don't provide any comprehensive info about it either.

Anyone already did this and can help me?

Thanks in advance! :)

***Edit:***
Locked or unlocked, there aren't 64 weapons on the shop. That's the problem.

Comment: Some weapons only unlocked after certain missions. How far through have you played?

Comment: I'm starting the game. But if went to the shop to count the weapons available there, and they aren't enough. Locked or unlocked.

Comment: More weapons appear in the shop. Not just those that are available but locked.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not going to go into detail here on how to unlock all the weapons, but they should all be accessible through the shop.

Any weapon that is locked should tell you what you need to get it when you hover over it.

Most will be getting to a certain part in the game, the best ones (the ones under the special category) require a certain amount of a particular event or task to be completed.

There are a few other guns in the game, through DLC, but these should automatically unlock during completion of the said DLC.

Comment: If you count the number of weapons on the shop, they don't reach 64. Locked or unlocked.

Comment: More will appear in the shop as you complete the main campaign missions, at least they did for me on the pc version, When I completed the game it was showing I had 63/64 unlocked with the 64th being a signature weapon that I did not care to unlock.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation @Phaeze! I'll try to complete the campaign and see how it goes :)

Comment: a good tip, too, you won't be able to get the good weapons until you hit North Kyrat. Once you cross the bridge, most of the weapons are accessible.